# SQL filter out ids that have multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have MySQL table in the following format

```
id     c1     c2
---------------------
id1    c1v1   c2v1  -> keep id1 even it has duplicates
id1    c1v1   c2v1
id2    c1v2   c2v2  -> filter out id2 because it has various c1, c2
id2    c1v2   c2v3
id3    c1v3   c2v4
....
```

Expected output:

```
id     c1     c2
---------------------
id1    c1v1   c2v1
id3    c1v3   c2v4
....
```

I want to retain only the records where id only has a unique c1, c2 value.
I do have a solution but it requires full table scan twice including a join which is very inefficient and I am wondering if there is a better way of doing it.

```
select 
    distinct id, c1, c2
from table 
inner join 
    (select 
        id, 
        count(distinct c1, c2) as counts
    from table 
    group by id
    having counts = 1) tmp
on table.id = tmp.id
```

Answer (score 1):

How about just using `group by`:

```
select id, min(c1) as c1, min(c2) as c2
from t
group by id
having min(c1) = max(c1) and min(c2) = max(c2)
```

If you want all the original records, then use `not exists`

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and
                        (t2.c1 <> t.c1 or t2.c2 <> t.c2)
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a self `LEFT JOIN` on different c1/c2 values, keeping only those rows where there is no matching row (i.e. different values for the same `id`) in the second table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id, t1.c1, t1.c2
FROM test t1
LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t2.id = t1.id AND (t2.c1 != t1.c1 OR t2.c2 != t1.c2)
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Output:

```
id      c1      c2
id1     c1v1    c2v1
id3     c1v3    c2v4
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vsE1hLAjtib9BCkJbNtT1D/0)